# angular-realworld-example-app (a github repository) - how to fix the issue below

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-cli

> my environment.

```
  export const environment = {
  production: false,
  api_url: 'localhost:3306/api'
};
```

> my local serve       Server: localhost:3306(MAMP）
>
> and here is his instruction: If you want to change the API URL to a
> local server, simply edit src/environments/environment.ts and change
> api_url to the local server's URL (i.e. localhost:3000/api)
>
> but here is my issue. when I use ng serve --open to
> http://localhost:4200/.   when I click sign in or sign out and then
> click, it just wouldn't work. and also tags or articles contained in that page show loading status.
>
> https://github.com/gothinkster/angular-realworld-example-app (original github address), and their app website: https://angular.realworld.io/
>
> regard thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to setup your environments correctly, follow these steps:

1. Create an environments folder under the 'src' folder, with the environment files needed, let's do for example 2 env files, one for local and one for production:

enviroment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    apiUrl: 'http://localhost:8182',
    hmr: false,
};
```

enviroment.prod.ts:

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    hmr       : false,
    apiUrl: 'http://productionURL.com:8182',
};
```

2. Setup angular.json correctly to enviroments:

Go to `angular.json`, then under 'configurations', and under 'production', put this there:

```
 "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
```

That's it. If you want to use the URL in your app, import it and use it like this:

```
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

  validate(email: string, password: string): Observable<LoginResponse> {
            return this.http.post<LoginResponse>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/auth`, { email, password });
        }
```

You can also choose the environment when building, like this:

```
ng build --prod --configuration production
```